# How can we decode non CSS codes like XZZX code with Pymatching?

Tags: surface-code, pymatching, minimum-weight-perfect-matching

I am trying to use Pymatching to decode some non CSS codes like the XZZX code. Pymatching is a perfect decoder for CSS codes, which can work effectively even of a large code distance. I have tried to decode XZZX code with Pymatching (circuits written with stim language), and certainly it gives wrong results (as d increases, logical error increases). I have learned that the algorithm in Pymatching (Sparse Blossom MWPM) performs well dealing with graph-like errors, while the correction operation of XZZX differs from that of CSS code, which leads to a wrong outcome. So my question is more technically:How could I modify the error-correction part in the Pymatching package and make it suitable for non CSS codes (e.g. XZZX code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting the idea CSS codes are "more matchable"? That's not true. I'm not even sure why you'd *think* it's true.

The XZZX and CSS surface codes have identical decoding graph structures. Decoding one *is* decoding the other. If you're getting the wrong answer, it's because of a bug in how you make the decoding graph or in how you apply the corrections. It's somewhere in your glue code.

I recommend using `pymatching.Matching.from_stim_circuit`, as this will avoid several potential bugs with how you configure pymatching.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Maybe I haven't made it clear that I'm doubting whether decoding process of CSS code can be directly applied to the XZZX code. I used Pymatching to decode in this way:   '''detector_error_model = circuit.detector_error_model(decompose_errors=True)\n
    matcher = pymatching.Matching.from_detector_error_model(detector_error_model)\n predictions = matcher.decode_batch(detection_events)'''  I know it will output a proper match for the XZZX code, but I'm wondering if the bit-flip operation from the match to the perdicted observable makes sense.

Comment: @QingweiWang Compare it to whether or not the observable was actually flipped and you'll see it tracks it just as well as in the CSS surface code.